Serial voting reversed
Today I checked CV and saw that I lost 270 reputation (and the associated marks towards badges) based off serial voting. I'm confused how this can be possible. Surely I would have noticed someone voting this many times across my posts, but most of the time I do not see dramatic changes in my reputation from day-to-day. I also haven't been very active on this site lately so the changes made must have been from a long time ago. What counts as serial voting on this site and how does it get "caught?" I'm not sure if there are specifics to CV that differ from other Exchange sites, hence my question.

(Same here. -110 wiped out ) But have you checked the Meta post: What is serial voting and how does it affect me?

-310 here but as usual I am never top at anything except possibly irritating pedantry. @whuber -690 and I stopped looking.

Probably best to not worry too much about internet points, and yet here I am posting about them.

There is no sin to admit that we all get bit enamored with rep points, @shawn. What is more important is that the system is working behind to remove any user or serial voting, for these reps never came from actually reading the said posts or benefitting from them but rather solely different purpose to, say, show appreciation for the said user (which one can do simply by reading one post and liking that in a normal way).

Big reversals happen now and then.  TBH I hadn't even noticed until seeing this on Hot Meta posts that anything had happened. Looking around a bit now it doesn't look like a particularly weird voting pattern so far (other than there being a fair amount of it, but that of itself doesn't sound bad; it had to have been over a pretty extended period), it seems like it's roughly proportional to people's activity and reputation. They (the people doing the reversing) can see stuff we don't so maybe there was a good reason for it. It's hard to speculate.

Sometimes I get a series which looks like someone has been following links through related posts and upvoted several. If such a thing happens, then I believe it should not be reversed. On the other hand, recently I had repeatingly receiving a big bunch of votes that seemed suspicious and made me believe that somehow site activity had increased (or alternatively I thought that the community user had been bumping up). If that was all due to a single person, or a person or related persons with multiple accounts, then it is rightfully reversed.

One individual recently had been voting extensively in a way that convincingly showed us they were unlikely to have been reading the posts.
In discussions with SE staff, I pointed out that the voting pattern looked reasonable: it comported with the recent activities and reputations of our users, paralleling the voting of many active people.  Their point, as communicated in a message to that user, explained

We recently noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to or from specific users. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts and downvote bad ones, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the post, not the person who wrote it. Please refrain from targeting specific users when voting.

I am not privy to the algorithms used to detect these patterns.  I can tell you that detecting voting irregularities involves a combination of surveillance by site mods along with systematic, automatic checking of voting patterns that has been ongoing since the beginning and is continually improved over time.

Thanks whuber. That seems to provide a direct answer to my question.

When I started on the site (long ago, but after the site was well established), one thing I did was go through the top posts of the top contributors.  I found this beneficial for me.  I upvoted very many, albeit not all, of them.  I did read them, but it may well have looked like 'serial voting'.

@gung I have done the same and feel SE is a little too strict in this regard.  However, the current situation was ongoing and egregious (according to the SE mod).

Given the number of posts here now on a wide array of topics, but which differ from each other, to greater or lesser extent, in their detail, won't it be increasingly likely for this to crop up? I know that when I am looking for input on something specific, I can quite quickly read and up-vote quite a number of answers as being helpful (often written by one of a few answers given we have some prolific contributors here). It strikes me that determining what is serial voting and what is normal activity will become increasingly difficult to differentiate.

@Gavin Yes, perhaps -- but since CV mods don't have access to detailed (second by second) logs of voting activities, we cannot make those determinations.
